# How to append a string into a front of an original text to make new text & then trip out the front string without affect the original text?

Tags: java, encode

Ok, here is my problem. I have a need to format the text based on the provided info. For a certain constraint, I can only append a control string into a front of the original text & when processing I have to trip out the front string to get original text. Not all text needs controlString.

Ex:

```
String originalText1="iPhone";
String controlString= "colorLevel=2*";
String newText1 =controlString+originalText1; //ie newText=colorLevel=2*iPhone

String originalText2="iPhone 3G"; // this originalText2 has no controlString
String newText2="iPhone 3G";

String originalText3="colorLevel=2*aaa"; // this has no controlString but its front is exactly the same as controlString
String newText3="colorLevel=2*aaa";

String originalText4="colorLevel=2*bbb"; // has controlString but at the same time its front is exactly the same as controlString
String controlString= "colorLevel=2*";
String newText4 =controlString+originalText4; // ie newText4=colorLevel=2*colorLevel=2*bbb
```

Ok, now i need a function to read all these new text. This function need to trip off the `controlString` to get the original.

So my question is, how to encode the original text in such a way that when we trip out the front string of the new text we won't affect the original text?

Comment: Use `Locale' then you do not need to worry about original text...[Locale tutorial here >>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html)

Comment: Not sure I understand... Are you saying that some part of your program has `newText1` and needs to extract `originalText1` from it?  That generally indicates poor design... the way to get the original text is not to lose it in the first place.  You may want to define a class that has two fields for the original text and the new text, or something along those lines.

Comment: Why not create a new class to represent this? It could have two properties: controlString and originalText. It would also have getters/setters for these two properties, along with a getCombinedText() method.

Comment: i knew it ugly but i have no other way to control it. Actually it's text in a cell of a cell table in GWT not pure Java

Comment: i was controled by other goole code so i can;t create new class like that cos it too complicated

Comment: Will you be able to add extra char along with controlString ? like unquie seperator ?

Comment: the original text is universal it could be anything, so we need to encode it in such a way that we can confident to append any string in front of it without losing it

Comment: So you are looking an unique control string for the given universal string. you dont have preference for the specific control string ?

Comment: no, the controlString can be anything, i just want to know the logics how can we manage this issue not a particular string

Answer (score 0):

If you don't prefer an constant Control String. You can build Control String based on the input.

```
static final String delimiterChar = "~";
static final String controlStringPattern = "^~-?\\d+~";

public static StringBuffer  encode(String orgText){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(delimiterChar);
    buffer.append(orgText.hashCode());
    buffer.append(delimiterChar);
    buffer.append(orgText);
    return buffer;

}
```

here i have added `"~"` before and after hashcode for an given input String.
Note** , String's hashcode method, will go through all characters in the string and perform multiplication of 31

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

So this would be based on the given String. and this may impact performance , if you are planning to use huge string as org String. And hashcode is built only once for an life time for the object.

You can replace the `hashcode` to any String you think as unquie.

To decode

```
public static String  decode(String orgText){
    return  orgText.replaceAll(controlStringPattern, "");
}
```

More detailed decode . This make sure the hashcode for the given number should match with Decoded String. double check

```
public static String  decode(String orgText){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(orgText);
    if (matcher.find()){
        String hashString = matcher.group();
        int hash = Integer.parseInt(hashString.substring(1,           hashString.length()-1));
        String txt = orgText.substring(hashString.length());
        if (txt.hashCode() == hash){
            return txt;
        }
    }
    return orgText;
}
```

To perform test

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //System.out.println(new String("~12345~").matches(controlStringPattern));
    String orgText = "Hi i am org Text";
    StringBuffer encodeText = encode(orgText);
    System.out.println("Orginial :" + orgText);
    System.out.println("Encoded :" + encodeText);
    System.out.println("Decoded :" + decode(encodeText.toString()));
    System.out.println("Decoded :" + decode("I am not Encoded"));

}
```

And the output as

```
Orginial :Hi i am org Text
Encoded :~-1828588409~Hi i am org Text
Decoded :Hi i am org Text
Decoded :I am not Encoded
```

if you want to get the control String alone..

```
public static String getControlStringifExists(String orgText){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(orgText);
    if (matcher.find()){
        String hashString = matcher.group();
        int hash = Integer.parseInt(hashString.substring(1, hashString.length()-1));
        String txt = orgText.substring(hashString.length());
        if (txt.hashCode() == hash){
            return hashString;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: is there any chance that after you encoded & the front of the encoded text is exactly the same as the ontrolString?

Comment: how do u so sure ur encode will be never generate string that have the front the same as the controlString?

Comment: IMO You wont get the String with "~"and its hashcodeand"~" prior to your text. it is very very rare situation. i would say 99.99% will work. Gave another way to avoid unnecessary matches

Comment: in program we need 100% not 99.99%, can u think a better one which sure 100%

Comment: So u mean orgText will never have any text that is = orgText.hashCode()

Comment: you cannot since there is no limitation from OrgText. you can add all special characters as control string. but still there is possibility be part of org text

Comment: alos i need controlString for other activity & ur code seem didn't take controlString out

Comment: i hope you understand the encode logic. it is blindly adding "~" and orgtext hashcode and then "~" . While decode , first we check the given string follows pattern as starts with "~" and any sequence of number and "~" and any character. if the match found then we might have possibility of encoded , else it wasnt encoded so we can return safely. if match found, we try to get the numbers and this number should be equal to the hashcode of orgtext . that is what we are doing in next step as double check . if that case we are removing prefix , else return as it is